# Moving to the previous screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I am an android beginner, and I have no android phone.

I am creating an android application, which contains 2 screens. I need to know how to come back, when I am in the 2nd screen. Do I have to specifically program a button in the xml file and code it or, can the user click the phone's back button to come back? (without any code) Or else, can the user slide it to the left side, so it will come back? (without any code).

Please help

Comment: What happens in the emulator?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: How to come back in emulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can the user click the phone's back button to come back? (without any code)

Yes. All Android phones have a back-button implemented for this purpose.

> Do I have to specifically program a button in the xml file and code it

You don't have to, but it is a possibility (although not recommended in most cases)

> Or else, can the user slide it to the left side, so it will come back? (without any code).

Normally no. Perhaps if you use a special kind of layout/activity that supports this as a built-in feature. I do not know of any that implements this though.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help Simon. I really appreciate it :)